# prestashop inserting values to the database showing unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, module, prestashop

In prestashop I am doing a module. Where I need to insert some values to the database. So for that I made my code look like this

```
DB::getInstance()->Execute('
    INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'socialapps` (`app_id`, `app_name`, `status`, `title`) VALUES (1, 'google plus', 0, 'google title')');
```

But every time I am getting error like Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in the line. So can someone kindly tell me what is the wrong here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why are you writing sql queries ? Why not you use PS insertion function.

PS db library provide another function for data insertion. Please look it at the following sample code

```
$insertData = array(
         'app_id'  => 1, 
         'app_name'  => 'google plus', 
         'status'   => 0, 
         'title'  => 'google title'
      );

 Db::getInstance()->insert("your table name", $insertData);
```

the $insertData array should be defined as so that the keys will be field names in the table and values should values for the db table.

Also please note that you dont need to attach the table prefix, because insert function add table prefix automatically.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You used quotes around 'google plus' instead of "double quotes". Your code should look like this and you'll be all set.

```
DB::getInstance()->Execute('
INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'socialapps` (`app_id`, `app_name`, `status`, `title`) VALUES (1, "google plus", 0, "google title")');
```